# What features do you miss most when switching from IntelliJ to XCode?

Tags: xcode, ide, intellij-idea

I've started to use XCode several months ago, after using IntelliJ for several years, and there are quite a few features that I really miss. XCode is not that bad, but it is lacking some basic stuff.

To trigger the discussion, here are some of the features that I miss most, who knows maybe someone from Apple will bump into this post and steal some Ideas :)

1. **Source-level error-highlighting**. The write-compile-fix cycle feels like going back in time 15 years ago to my early C days. Many errors can be spotted without having to compile and Java IDEs have been doing it for years.
2. **A decent debugger**. This is a bit unfair because IntelliJ's debugger is the best I've used so far, but XCode's debugger is at least 5 years behind and Apple has a few more developers than JetBrains...
3. **Stronger re-factoring**. A no-brainer I guess. XCode has some renaming capabilities (which they call re-factoring), but they are very few.
4. **Override method**. This one is really amazing. XCode doesn't have an "override method" command which lets you choose the method you want to override from a super class or protocol. You need to go to the documentation or header file and start copy-pasting.
5. **Duplicate selected line(s)**. I've bumped into some posts that offer workarounds for this via custom key-binding, but none of them works, at least for me.
6. **Go to last edit point**. Bummer! Come on Apple, this one is so easy to implement and  so useful!
7. **A better open quickly feature**. IntelliJ's quick find of classes/files/text is so much better...

Turns out that my list goes on and on, so I'll stop here...

***What other features do you miss most in your transition to XCode??***

Ori

Comment: Agreed that the refactoring tools in Xcode leave a LOT to be desired. That being said, I use them all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the better Open Quickly feature - Code Pilot for Xcode might help here :)
http://macoscope.net/en/mac/codepilot/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we soon will get all those features. According to an interview in JavaPosse #283, [Jetbrains is working on an IDE for Objective-C](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5247088) :)

Answer (score 1):

Intentions are a great tool in IntelliJ.  They quickly help identify things I might have otherwise missed.  The new Build and Analyze feature in XCode 3.2 is a good start in the right direction.

And they just announced IntelliJ is now available via Open Source.  I hope this means we start seeing more adoption, perhaps more plugins to make it more useful for Mac/iPhone development.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on all your points. But I'd also like to have better local revision tracking (Actually this is from eclipse, rather than IntelliJ, but still). I usually realise I should have taken a snapshot of the code *after* I've made a mess.